# Out of memory on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, 22.04, uefi

My system is Gigabyte X670 Aorus Elite AX, AMD Ryzen9 7950X, 4x 32GB Kingston 5200 RAM, NVidia RTX A4000. Ubuntu 20.04. and Windows 10 are sharing Kingston SKC3000D2048G.

After a month of work, a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04. (dualbooted with UEFI Windows 10) stopped booting showing:

```
Error: out of memory.
Press any key to continue...
```

After some reading on the Internet about possible a bug in 22.04, I decided on a quick solution by reinstalling an older version 20.04 from a USB. After the installation, the OS did not boot at all and showed the same error message again. The next screen looks like this:

[image]

I suspect a hardware problem which I'm not capable to detect.